# Terminal services verus remote desktop on a SBS 2008 server

Tags: remote-desktop, terminal-server, windows-sbs-2008

On SBS 2003 you could have the console login, and 2 admin users logged in remotely. On a recent SBS 2008 server I installed, it appears, by default that it is using remote desktop and only allows one user at a time, either console or remote. Can it be changed to act like SBS 2003?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/sbs/archive/2008/09/26/can-i-use-terminal-services-in-sbs-2008.aspx), you cannot use Terminal Services in SBS2008

Comment: TS is different from Remote Desktop. And you can use TS in 2008 Premium (as it comes with a 2nd 2008 license).

Comment: Sorry, that should have read SBS 2008 Premium

Comment: The OP stated SBS2008 and not the Premium version.

Comment: To clarifiy terms Chad is trying to use a feautre built into most Microsoft Server versions from 2000 and up called "Remote Desktop Administration". Farseeker is correct you cannot run Terminal Services which allows non-admins to connect and more than two as well. They are very similar which can make them confusing (thank you Microsoft).

Answer (score 0):

To be clear all of my information came from this webpage:
http://blog.mpecsinc.ca/2009/03/sbs-2008-remove-single-ts-user.html

1. Click Start and type: Terminal Services Configuration [Enter] (the console will come up immediately while typing)
2. Click Continue at the UAC prompt.
3. Double click on the Restrict each user to a single session setting.
4. Uncheck the setting.
5. Click Apply and OK.

Answer (score 0):

He's not talking about the 'no TS' he's talking about how by default in server 2008 only one admin can TS into the box at a time.

From Start Run
tsconfig.msc
(uncheck Single connection)
For the TS Remote access

Then you can have two Admins and use Shadow for training.